# cannot do the mapping from a jsp page to controller page

Tags: spring-mvc

only show the register page after clicking on the submit button shows the error as

```
http status 404 
request source is not available
```

jsp page is:

```
     <div>
        <form:form method="post" action="/log" modelAttribute="user">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Task id :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form:form>

    </div>
```

controller page is:

```
                 { public class HomePageController 
  {@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value="/log",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getUserLIst(@RequestParams("id")String id  @ModelAttribute User user)
{

    List<User> userList = userService.getUserList(id);
    return new ModelAndView("userList", "userList", userList);
}
```

web.xml:

```
<display-name>SpringDatabase</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>register.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

spring.xml is:

```
<!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<!-- declaring base package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="default-package" />

<!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- declare beans -->
<bean id="userDao" class="UserDaoImpl" />
<bean id="userService" class="UserServiceImpl" />

<!-- declare datasource bean -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eximat" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="mysql" />
</bean>
```

userlist.jsp is:

```
               table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="heading">User Id</td>
            <td class="heading">First Name</td>
            <td class="heading">Last Name</td>
            <td class="heading">Gender</td>
            <td class="heading">City</td>

        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.userId}</td>
                <td>${user.firstName}</td>
                <td>${user.lastName}</td>
                <td>${user.gender}</td>
                <td>${user.city}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to minimize the code snippets by removing irrelevant code if any.

Comment: If you click on the submit button, can you see what 'link' is directed to? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
use this

<div>
      <form:form method="post" action="log" modelAttribute="user">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Task id :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form:form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URL for jsp file as that can be the only reason for getting 404 error. As http is not getting requested resource in URL so there is some mistake with your url.